# Python 3 - changing the return value

Tags: python-3.x, return-value

I have written a code which outputs the sub tokens a word. I have defined many cases for which it works perfectly except for one case for which it returns :

```
['']
```

instead of :

```
[]
```

Is there a way that i can ask python to print the square brackets, without the apostrophe's whenever that case occurs?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using? It'll help us fix your problem.

Comment: Not sure we can help you then because we cant tell what is causing the '' to occur.

Comment: can i write a case statement or something similar to print [] whenever [''] this occurs

Comment: It appears you're returning an array with an empty string, instead of an empty array. You can write a conditional (if) to check for this and fudge the output but a more proper approach would be to return an empty array to start with. Without seeing code, there's not much else we can do to help

Comment: The question was a bit clunky to read - I think this makes it more readable.

Comment: I'm taking a wild guess. Probably using some regex you tried to compare a text and it matched before the beginning or after the end! If this resembles your case, you can try modifying the regex by using start (^) or end ($) marker. Its a wild guess though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a list containing an empty string you can check for it and print the `[]` symbols (I really don't see a reason for this other than making your code "nicer"(?)):

```
>>> a = [""]
>>> print(a)
['']
>>> if a==[""]:
        print("[]")
[]
```